# enumerateAssetsUsingBlock crash with SQLite error code 14

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios8.1, alassetlibrary

SQLite error code 14 is SQLITE_CANTOPEN.

The crash happens only in iOS8.1 of our app.

The process is like below.

Main->Album Select View(Select Camera Roll)->Photo Select View->Back to Main-> Album Select View (Select Camera Roll)->Photo Select View(Crash)

We reload the assetGroup objects in init of Album Select View.(ALAssetsLibrary is also initialized)

I hope someone could give me some hint about this issue.

Comment: do you do any threading? sounds a bit like the main thread  has it and then another thread/process tries to open it!?

Comment: @Daij-Djan No thread/process is used except loading the assets groups.The crash happens only in camera roll.

Comment: then - without some code I am clueless

Comment: @Daij-Djan I answered my question.Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's really a weird problem.

The reason is this piece of code.

```
[assetsGroup setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]]
```

After I delete it, it turns all right.
And the crash only occurs in iOS8.1 iPhone version.